# Hostname not working with docker compose and redis

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, redis, activemq-artemis

I have a web application that makes use of a postgres database, a redis and an artemis server. All this working in docker containers but I can't get the application to connect to redis or artemis using the container name (with postgres it works). My docker compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  my_web_app:
    container_name: "my_web_app"
    image: my_image
    restart: always
    environment:
     REDIS_HOST: ${REDIS_HOST}
     REDIS_PORT: ${REDIS_PORT}
     ARTEMIS_HOST: ${ARTEMIS_HOST}
     ARTEMIS_PORT: ${ARTEMIS_PORT}
     ARTEMIS_USER: ${ARTEMIS_USER}
     JDBC_URL: ${JDBC_URL}
     JDBC_USERNAME: ${JDBC_USERNAME}
     JDBC_PASSWORD: ${JDBC_PASSWORD}
        ...
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - my_redis
      - my_artemis
      - my_postgres
    networks:
      - my_network

  my_postgres:
    container_name: "my_postgres"
    image: "postgis/postgis"
    environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: ${JDBC_USERNAME}
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${JDBC_PASSWORD}
     POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - my_network

  my_redis:
    container_name: "my_redis"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - my_network


  my_artemis:
    container_name: "my_artemis"
    image: vromero/activemq-artemis:2.16.0
    environment:
       ARTEMIS_USERNAME: quarkus
       ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: quarkus
       ENABLE_JMX_EXPORTER: "true"
    ports:
      - 61616:61616
      - 8161:8161
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - my_network:

networks:
  my_network:
```

I have tried setting network aliases, domainname or hostname but nothing works.
My health check:

```
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "checks": [
        {
            "name": "Database connections health check",
            "status": "UP"
        },
        {
            "name": "Redis connection health check",
            "status": "DOWN",
            "data": {
                "reason": "client [<default>]: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Artemis JMS health check",
            "status": "DOWN"
        }
    ]
}
```

My .env:

```
REDIS_HOST=my_redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
ARTEMIS_HOST=my_artemis
ARTEMIS_PORT=61616
ARTEMIS_USER=quarkus
ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=quarkus
JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://my_postgres:5432/my_db
JDBC_USERNAME=quarkus
JDBC_PASSWORD=quarkus
DB_NAME=my_db
```

My quarkus application.properties

```
quarkus.artemis.url=tcp://${ARTEMIS_HOST}:${ARTEMIS_PORT}
quarkus.artemis.username=${ARTEMIS_USER}
quarkus.artemis.password=${ARTEMIS_PASSWORD}
quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://${REDIS_HOST}:${REDIS_PORT}
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=${JDBC_URL}
quarkus.datasource.username=${JDBC_USERNAME}
quarkus.datasource.password=${JDBC_PASSWORD}
```

My postgres setup (which works):

> jdbc:postgresql://my_postgres:5433/db_name

My configuration for redis and artemis:

> redis://my_redis:6379

> tcp://my_artemis:61616

The only thing that has worked is setting the network and fixed ips and using the ips instead of the container names but I want to use the container names. Any ideas?

Comment: your docker-compose file looks good. you should use the service name which you seem to do. I doubt the application code. it does not seem to use `my_redis:6379` instead it seems to assume `localhost:6379` inside the container.

Comment: @RamPrakash The application code is correct, if I use the ip of a physical machine (both redis and artemis work ok). And using the configured ips of docker containers as well. I am using quarkus, maybe it is the framework that has a problem, but with postgres it works correctly.

Comment: Also I have retrieved the value from the redis host in the application code and it was correct, but the value in the healthcheck seems wrong: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: What's the actual error message you're getting?  It sounds like your application configuration is right, but can you include it in the question just to be sure?

Comment: can you include the environment variables & values in the question instead of `...` - `environment:  
        ...`

Comment: @RamPrakash I have edited the question with environment properties, the application properties and the .env file

Comment: I don't see the problem either but you could try to use links with aliases in your compose file. I know it's kinda deprecated but worth a try to check if the problem is in network setting: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I have fixed my problem, both the redis and artemis services in the docker compose should be named just like this "redis" and "artemis". I don't know if it's the fault of the Quarkus framework

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem but I don't quite understand the reason, I suppose it is a problem with the Quarkus framework. I had to call the services "redis" and "artemis".

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  my_web_app:
    container_name: "my_web_app"
    image: my_image
    restart: always
    environment:
        ...
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - artemis
      - my_postgres
    networks:
      - my_network

  my_postgres:
    container_name: "my_postgres"
    image: "postgis/postgis"
    environment:
        ...
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - my_network

  redis:
    container_name: "my_redis"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - my_network


  artemis:
    container_name: "my_artemis"
    image: vromero/activemq-artemis:2.16.0
    environment:
      ARTEMIS_USERNAME: quarkus
      ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: quarkus
      ENABLE_JMX_EXPORTER: "true"
    ports:
      - 61616:61616
      - 8161:8161
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - my_network:

networks:
  my_network:
```

And configure its values in the environment variables file:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
ARTEMIS_HOST=artemis
ARTEMIS_PORT=61616
```

This way it works correctly.

Comment: so basically if you change the redis service name to `my_redis` and even if you update `REDIS_HOST=my_redis` is not working?  Is this not weird to you?

Comment: That's. I get the error "Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379". I think it is a problem with the Quarkus components because with a Postgres it works ok.

Comment: do you have any sample project to upload in github to check. for me it does not make sense.

Comment: @RamPrakash sorry for the delay but it seems this is the problem https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16037

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!